# Install FFMPEG on Shared Hosting server

Tags: linux, godaddy, shared-hosting, ffmpeg

I have godaddy shared hosting server running under linux. I am trying to install ffmpeg on server but I am unable to install it.

on godaddy, yum is not working.

Anybody have successfully installed FFMPEG on shared hosting? Can you please let me know the steps to install?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on godaddy, yum is not working.

Of course it's not working, because it's not your server to install packages on.

You may be able to find a statically-linked binary of ffmpeg around, which you should be able to run in a shared hosting environment.

However, if you really need the ability to add/remove packages like this, switch to a VPS solution instead of shared hosting.

Comment: Dont have option to move to VPS or DS :(
Do you have list or steps to install statically-linked binary of ffmpeg on server?

Comment: I just need to install FFMPEG on shared hosting. other packages are supported by godaddy. so not affordable to purchase VPS or DS for one package.

Comment: No, sorry I don't.

Comment: This is one of the sacrifices you made by choosing shared hosting - it's not your server, and as such, you're stuck using whatever packages are provided by your hosting provider.

Comment: Even if he finds a statically-linked binary, GoDaddy's going to get mad about the resulting CPU load.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Yep, good point.

Answer (score 1):

As ErikA recommends, you will need to find a FFMPEG binary that will run on your particular GoDaddy hosting account.

You will need to upload the binary to your account, preferably in an area outside of the document root.  Be sure to set the permissions on the binary to be executed.

In your application, you will need to set the path to the binary location.  Most applications will be looking for the default location so this will fail.

Here is an older post on this topic.

http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/06/28/compiled-linux-ffmpeg-binary-for-gallery2-download.html

Comment: GoDaddy'll likely disable an account using as much CPU as ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to [try this method](https://serverfault.com/questions/942701/how-to-install-a-binary-package-on-a-shared-hosting-for-example-aqbanking-or-m/942702#942702).

It should be adaptable for each package that can be compiled. You use a docker container with the same distribution GoDaddy is using, compile additional libraries and set the lib path.